# How efficently change fetched data from django raw query

Tags: python, mysql, django

For my project, I needed to run a raw query to increase performance. The problem is here that for one part I need to change value of fetched data to sth else(gregorian date to jalali) and this causes my performance to decrease a lot.

```
cursor.execute("select date,number from my_db)
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:
       break
   data.append(row)
```

This section longs about 1 min for 4 million data, but I need to chanfe date like this:

```
cursor.execute("select date,number from my_db)
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:
       break

    row = list(row)
    row[0] = (jdatetime.datetime.fromgregorian(datetime=row[0]).strftime(                                                       '%y/%m/%d, %H:%m'))

   data.append(row)
```

this causes my code to run in 7 min. I wonder if there is a way to do this change efficiently

Answer (score -1):

First part should not take 1 min to finish. Instead of raw sql and a loop, do

```
data = YourModel.objects.values_list('date', 'number')
```

For the second part, you can make your own SQL function.
https://raresql.com/tag/iranian-calendar-to-georgian-calendar-in-sql-server/